# Constructor Modified CSR matrix from file:

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix

I'm implementing a modified compressed sparse row matrix class, I wrote the constructor (for this particular storage [link](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/wagner/node83.html)) taking matrix as:

```
std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>>
```

or from a file (the constructor take the file name) in which the matrix is written in the classic way:

```
0 0 0 0
5 8 0 0
0 0 3 0 
0 6 0 0
```

Now I seen that for testing the storage efficiency there is a site (Matrix Marker) in which the matrix are stored by coordinate and relative element (non zero one)
like:

```
   # matrix sparse 
    10 10 10
    1 1 11.06
    1 6 16.45
    4 5 45.22
    2 1 21.43
    3 9 39.45
    8 1 81.13
    6 9 69.67
    2 9 0.29
    5 4 54.12
    1 9 19.12
```

where the line after the header contain the number of row, number of columns and the number of zero of the matrix, than start index-i, index-j value

here the class that I wrote

so I want integrate such constructor in my class... but is not so easy

```
# include <initializer_list>
# include <vector>
# include <iosfwd>
# include <string>
# include <cstdlib>
# include <cassert>
# include <iomanip>
# include <cmath>
# include <set>
# include <fstream>
# include <algorithm>
# include <exception>
# include<iostream>

template <typename data_type>
class MCSRmatrix;             

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os ,const MCSRmatrix<T>& m) noexcept ;

template <typename data_type>
class MCSRmatrix {

   public:
      using itype = std::size_t ;

      template <typename T>
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os ,const MCSRmatrix<T>& m) noexcept ;
      constexpr MCSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::vector<data_type>> rows);

      constexpr MCSRmatrix(const std::string& fname) noexcept;
     const data_type& operator()(const itype r , const itype c) const noexcept ;

      data_type operator()(const itype r , const itype c) noexcept ;

      auto constexpr printMCSR() const noexcept ;

      auto constexpr nnz()const noexcept { return aa_.size(); }

   private:

   std::vector<data_type> aa_ ;    // vector of value 
     std::vector<itype>     ja_ ;    // pointer vector 

     int dim ; 

     std::size_t constexpr findIndex(const itype row ,  const itype col) const noexcept ;
};
template <typename T>
constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix( std::initializer_list<std::vector<T>> rows)
{
      this->dim  = rows.size();
      auto _rows = *(rows.begin());

      aa_.resize(dim+1);
      ja_.resize(dim+1);

      if(dim != _rows.size())
      {
          throw std::runtime_error("Error in costructor! MCSR format require square matrix!");  
      }

      itype w = 0 ;
      ja_.at(w) = dim+2 ;
      for(auto ii = rows.begin(), i=1; ii != rows.end() ; ++ii, i++)
      {
          for(auto ij = ii->begin(), j=1, elemCount = 0 ; ij != ii->end() ; ++ij, j++ )   
          {
              if(i==j)
                 aa_[i-1] = *ij ;
              else if( i != j && *ij != 0 )
              {   
                 ja_.push_back(j); 
                 aa_.push_back(*ij); 
                 elemCount++ ;
              }
              ja_[i] = ja_[i-1] + elemCount;           
          }
      }     
      printMCSR();
}


//
//
template <typename T>
constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix(const std::string& fname) noexcept
{
   std::ifstream f(fname , std::ios::in );
   
   if(!f)
   {
      std::cerr << "Error unable to open file " << fname 
                << "\nError occurred in MSRmatrix constructor\n EXIT -1" << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::string line;
      std::string temp;
      std::size_t i=0 , j=0 ;
      while(getline(f,line))
      {
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        if(i==0) while(ss >> temp) j++ ;
        i++ ;
      }
      if(i != j) 
      {
         std::cerr << "Error in MSR Matrix constructor:\n"
                   << "Matrix MSR must be square! ~ program terminate with -1" << std::endl;    
         //exit(-1);   
      }
      else
      {
         f.clear();
         f.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );
         
         this->dim = i;
         aa_.resize(dim+1); 
         ja_.resize(dim+1);
     
         itype w = 0 ;
         ja_.at(w) = dim+2 ;
         T elem = 0;
         for(auto i=1; i <= dim  ; i++)
         {
          getline(f,line);
          std::istringstream ss(line);
          for(auto j=1, elemCount = 0 ; j <= dim ; j++ )   
          {
              ss >> elem ;           
              if(i==j)
                 aa_[i-1] = elem ;
              else if( i != j && elem != 0 )
              {   
                 ja_.push_back(j); 
                 aa_.push_back(elem); 
                 elemCount++ ;
              }
              ja_[i] = ja_[i-1] + elemCount;           
          }
         }     
# ifdef __DEBUG__
    printMCSR();  
# endif
   }
 }
}






template <typename T>
constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix(const std::size_t& n ) noexcept
{
         this->dim = n;
         aa_.resize(dim+1); 
         ja_.resize(dim+1);

      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < aa_.size()-1 ; i++)
        aa_.at(i) = 1 ;    

      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < ja_.size() ; i++)
        ja_.at(i) = aa_.size()+1 ;   


}     


template <typename T>
std::size_t constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::findIndex(const itype row ,  const itype col) const noexcept 
{    
     assert( row > 0 && row <= dim && col > 0 && col <= dim ); 
     if(row == col)
     {
       return row-1;
     }
     int i = -1;

      for(int i = ja_.at(row-1)-1 ; i < ja_.at(row)-1 ; i++ )
      {
            if( ja_.at(i) == col ) 
            { 
              return i ;
            }
      }
      return -1;
}


template <typename T>
inline auto constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::printMCSR() const noexcept 
{
      for(auto& x : aa_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;

      for(auto& x : ja_ )
          std::cout << x << ' ' ;
      std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
const T& MCSRmatrix<T>::operator()(const itype r , const itype c) const noexcept 
{     
     auto i = findIndex(r,c); 
     if( i != -1 && i < aa_.size() )
     {      
            return aa_.at(i) ;
     }
     else
     {
            return aa_.at(dim) ;
     }       
}


template <typename T>
T MCSRmatrix<T>::operator()(const itype r , const itype c) noexcept 
{     
     auto i = findIndex(r,c); 
     if( i != -1 && i < aa_.size() )
     {      
            return aa_.at(i) ;
     }
     else
     {
            return aa_.at(dim) ;
     }       
}

// non member operator

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os ,const MCSRmatrix<T>& m) noexcept 
{
     for(std::size_t i=1 ; i <= m.dim ; i++ )
     {       
         for(std::size_t j=1 ; j <= m.dim ; j++)   
            os << std::setw(8) << m(i,j) << ' ' ;
         os << std::endl;   
     } 
     return os;
}
```

here the main:

```
int main() {

   MCSRmatrix<int> m01 =  {{0,1,0,0},{0,3,0,9},{2,0,0,3},{3,0,0,1}};
   MCSRmatrix<int> m02 =  {{1,1,0,14},{0,22,0,3},{0,0,33,34},{0,0,1,44}};


    MCSRmatrix<double> m3  = {{1.01, 0 , 0,0}, {0, 4.07, 0,0},{0,0,6.08,0},{1.06,0,2.2,9.9} };   

  MCSRmatrix<double> m4  = {{ 1.21, 0 , 1.06,0 }, {0, 3.31, 1.06,0},{0,1.06,-6.01,0},{4.12,0,1.06,-8.3}};    
  MCSRmatrix<double> m5("input.dat");



   cout << m03 << endl;
   cout << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

now I was trying yo modified the constructor that takes a string as argument in this way:

```
   template <typename T>
    inline constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix(const std::string& fname) 
    {
       std::ifstream f(fname , std::ios::in );
       
       if(!f)
       {
          std::string mess = "Error unable to open file " + fname + 
                     "\nError occurred in MCSRmatrix constructor\n EXCEPTION THROWN" ;
          throw OpeningFileException(mess.c_str());
       }
    
       if( fname.find(".mtx") != std::string::npos )
       {
          auto i=0 , i1= 0 , j1= 0;    
          T elem =0;
          std::string line;
          getline(f,line); // jump out the header
          
          line = " " ;
          
          while(getline(f,line)) 
          {
             std::istringstream ss(line) ;  
             if(i==0)   
             {
                ss >> i1 ;
                ss >> j1 ;
                ss >> nnz ;
                
                  if( i1 != j1 )
                  {
                    std::string mess ="Error in MCSR Matrix constructor:\n MCRS Matrix must be square! EXCEPTION THROWN" ;    
                    throw InvalidSizeException(mess.c_str());      
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    dim = i1;
                    aa_.resize(i1+1);
                    ja_.resize(i1+1);
                    
                    for(i=0; i < dim+1 ; i++ )
                    {
                         ja_.at(i) = aa_.size() ;
                    }  
                  }  
             } 
             else
             {
                ss >> i1 >> j1 >> elem ;
    
                if(i1 == j1)      // diagonal element
                {
                    aa_.at(i1-1) = elem ;  
                }
                else if( i1 != j1 )
                {
                   for(i=i1 ; i < dim+1 ; i++)   
                   {
            //            std::cout << i1 << '\t' <<  << std::endl;
                        ja_.at(i)++ ;
                   }
                   //ja_.at(i1)++ ;   
                   
                   ja_.insert(ja_.begin() + (ja_.at(i1-1)) , j1-1  );
                   aa_.insert(aa_.begin() + (ja_.at(i1-1)) , elem);   
    
                }
    
             }
             i++;
          }
          printModCompressed();
       }
       else
       {
          std::string line;
          std::string temp;
          std::size_t i=0 , j=0 ;
          while(getline(f,line))
          {
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            if(i==0) while(ss >> temp) j++ ;
            i++ ;
          }
          if(i != j) 
          {
             std::string mess = "Error in MCSR Matrix constructor:\n MCRS Matrix must be square! EXCEPTION THROWN" ;    
             throw InvalidSizeException(mess.c_str());   
          }
          else
          {
             f.clear();
             f.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );
             
             this->dim = i;
             aa_.resize(dim+1); 
             ja_.resize(dim+1);
         
             std::size_t w = 0 ;
             ja_.at(w) = dim+2 ;
             T elem = 0;
             for(auto i=1; i <= dim  ; i++)
             {
              getline(f,line);
              std::istringstream ss(line);
              for(auto j=1, elemCount = 0 ; j <= dim ; j++ )   
              {
                  ss >> elem ;           
                  if(i==j)
                     aa_[i-1] = elem ;
                  else if( i != j && elem != 0 )
                  {   
                     ja_.push_back(j); 
                     aa_.push_back(elem); 
                     elemCount++ ;
                  }
                  ja_[i] = ja_[i-1] + elemCount;           
              }
             }     
    # ifdef __TESTING__
        printMCSR(); 
   # endif
       }
     }
    }
```

that looks strange because the 2 vector AA and JA looks fine...

but give me very wrong results... I don't know how I can construct this matrix from mtx file...

**EDIT**

I solved:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr MCSRmatrix<T>::MCSRmatrix(const std::string& fname) 
{
   std::ifstream f(fname , std::ios::in );
   
   if(!f)
   {
      std::string mess = "Error unable to open file " + fname + 
                 "\nError occurred in MCSRmatrix constructor\n EXCEPTION THROWN" ;
      throw OpeningFileException(mess.c_str());
   }

   if( fname.find(".mtx") != std::string::npos )
   {
      auto i=0 , i1= 0 , j1= 0;    
      T elem =0;
      std::string line;
      getline(f,line); // jump out the header
      
      line = " " ;
      
      while(getline(f,line)) 
      {
         std::istringstream ss(line) ;  
         if(i==0)   
         {
            ss >> i1 ;
            ss >> j1 ;
            ss >> nnz ;
            
              if( i1 != j1 )
              {
                std::string mess ="Error in MCSR Matrix constructor:\n MCRS Matrix must be square! EXCEPTION THROWN" ;    
                throw InvalidSizeException(mess.c_str());      
              }
              else
              {
                dim = i1;
                aa_.resize(i1+1);
                ja_.resize(i1+1);
                
                for(i=0; i < dim+1 ; i++ )
                {
                     ja_.at(i) = dim+2 ;
                }  
              }  
         } 
         else
         {
            ss >> i1 >> j1 >> elem ;

            if(i1 == j1)      // diagonal element
            {
                aa_.at(i1-1) = elem ;  
            }
            else if( i1 != j1 )
            {
               for(i=i1 ; i < dim+1 ; i++)   
               {
                    ja_.at(i)++ ;
               }
               
               ja_.insert(ja_.begin() + (ja_.at(i1-1)-1) , j1  );
               aa_.insert(aa_.begin() + (ja_.at(i1-1)-1) , elem);   

            }

         }
         i++;
      }
      printModCompressed();
   }
   else
   {
      std::string line;
      std::string temp;
      std::size_t i=0 , j=0 ;
      while(getline(f,line))
      {
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        if(i==0) while(ss >> temp) j++ ;
        i++ ;
      }
      if(i != j) 
      {
         std::string mess = "Error in MCSR Matrix constructor:\n MCRS Matrix must be square! EXCEPTION THROWN" ;    
         throw InvalidSizeException(mess.c_str());   
      }
      else
      {
         f.clear();
         f.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );
         
         this->dim = i;
         aa_.resize(dim+1); 
         ja_.resize(dim+1);
     
         std::size_t w = 0 ;
         ja_.at(w) = dim+2 ;
         T elem = 0;
         for(auto i=1; i <= dim  ; i++)
         {
          getline(f,line);
          std::istringstream ss(line);
          for(auto j=1, elemCount = 0 ; j <= dim ; j++ )   
          {
              ss >> elem ;           
              if(i==j)
                 aa_[i-1] = elem ;
              else if( i != j && elem != 0 )
              {   
                 ja_.push_back(j); 
                 aa_.push_back(elem); 
                 elemCount++ ;
              }
              ja_[i] = ja_[i-1] + elemCount;           
          }
         }     
# ifdef __TESTING__
   // printMCSR(); 
   printModCompressed();
# endif
   }
 }
}
```